# How to store long strings in Python during the execution of the program

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need a most efficient way to store long string (~2mb) during the execution of the program.

There is a loop and every iteration creates very long string. Lines of this string appears and I need to store them. There is also condition independent of the string. If condition is true I want to print this string. If condition is false, there is no operations. After iteration the string is no longer needed. Then next iteration creates another string.

I consider the variable. When line appears I want to add a line to the variable:

```
big_string = ''  
while true:
    big_string += line
    [...]
    big_string += line
    if condition:
        print big_string
    big_string = ''
```

Is it a good way to handle that ?

Comment: `big_string += line` will be inefficient; better performance if you treat it as an array e.g. `big_string = []; big_string.append(line)` then use `print '\n'.join(big_string)` to convert back to an array. Otherwise, you do a _lot_ of copying of long strings...

Comment: brilliant idea! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main options for data storage would be:

Variable,(as you have done)
 array,
 or a text file.

If you want to keep the strings separate and independent from one another I would recommend an array so you can independently call each index, however if that does not matter and you want to simply call the whole thing I see no issue with your current structure.

Comment: A agree. Doing it in memory as you have done seems like the best option.